# ffmpeg add music to video playing after video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` to create slideshow of images.

I have to add music in the backgroup which will be played to the size of the slideshow *(slicing audio if audio length is greater than video or repeating audio if audio length is shorter than video)*

This is what my script is

```
ffmpeg -y \
-loop 1 -i in1.png \
-loop 1 -i in2.png \
-loop 1 -i in3.png \
-loop 1 -i in4.png \
-loop 1 -i in5.png \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setsar=1:1[v0]; \
 [1:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setsar=1:1[v1]; \
 [2:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setsar=1:1[v2]; \
 [3:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setsar=1:1[v3]; \
 [4:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setsar=1:1[v4]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,setsar=1:1[v]" -i music.mp3 -shortest -map "[v]" -aspect 16:9 -r 24 shortSlideshow1234.mp4;
```

This generates output, but slideshow is silent and there is no music in the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also map the audio:

```
ffmpeg -y \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -i in1.png \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -i in2.png \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -i in3.png \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -i in4.png \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -i in5.png \
-i music.mp3 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setsar=1[v0]; \
 [1:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setsar=1[v1]; \
 [2:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setsar=1[v2]; \
 [3:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setsar=1[v3]; \
 [4:v]trim=duration=6,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1,setsar=1[v4]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" -map 5:a shortSlideshow1234.mp4
```